# How do I insert email to another table without have a duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have 2 tables in my database. `users` and `combineusers`

I want to insert current email on `users` to `combineusers` without have duplicate email.

```
INSERT INTO combineusers (Email)
SELECT Email FROM users
```

What is correct statement to skip existing email address on `combineusers`

Comment: do you want to update existing ones or just skip?

Comment: if on table `combineusers` already have the email address just skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a left exclusion join.
I'm not sure the subselect is needed, I know it's needed on an update.
The subselect forces MySQL to materialize the inner select into a temp table and do the insert from there so that you're not inserting into the same table your selecting from.

```
INSERT INTO combineusers (Email) 
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT u.Email FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN combineusers c ON (u.email = c.email)
  WHERE c.email IS NULL
) sub
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has **non-standard** option to skip duplicates instead of throwing an error:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO combineusers (Email)
SELECT Email FROM users
```

I quote the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
>   aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued.

Comment: So `Email` should has etither `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO combineusers (Email) 
SELECT Email FROM users u
LEFT JOIN combineusers c ON c.Email = u.Email
WHERE c.Email IS NULL
```

OR using `NOT EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO combineusers (Email) 
SELECT Email FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (
       SELECT Email 
       FROM combineusers c 
       WHERE c.Email = u.Email
      )
```

Comment: @Johan : this is exactly what I've said in PS :)

Comment: Your wording of the PS is not clear, your answer and your comment are in exact opposition.

Comment: Perhaps this is because I'm not a native English speaker, basically my query express things better than myself :) - I've not used `EXISTS` in the final query when figured out that MySql does not provide EXISTS feature

Comment: MySQL **does** provide exists, you are misinformed.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
INSERT INTO combineusers (Email) SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM users
```

Comment: +1 for remembering to eliminate duplicate email addresses from users. Although it's only half the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clearly put, but if I understand correctly what you mean is you want to take email address from `users` and insert them into `combineusers`, while avoiding inserting any email address which are already in `combineusers`. Other answerers have already shown a few ways to manipulate the statements, but another way to achieve this might be to declare the `Email` field of `combineusers` unique.